# if we have transaction management at database level than why we put the transaction management in our code

Tags: spring, transactions

I was going through the transaction management provided by Spring , but just for curiosity want to know if we transaction management is provided by Database than why we are using the transnational management  provide by JTA, Spring etc.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can completely avoid using transactional annotations in your code (and basically you should stick this approach). Because every transaction will be committed on each successful DB call implicitly.

But **sometimes** you have to make several operations (queries) in a single transaction: withdraw money (from `account` table) and ship goods (from `store` table). In this case, you cannot avoid transaction management:

```
class Processor {
    ...
    @Transactional
    void purchase(){
        accountService.withdraw(200);
        storeService.ship("goods")
    }
}
```